# Best tools & settings for `VSCode` for *offline* Substrate development

Tags: rust

Substrate builds are *resource intensive*. Running some of rust's best-in-class tools like [`rust-analyzer`](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/) at least with default settings leads to continuous full use of most resources and take frustratingly long to start working, if they do at all.

What are the best tools & tips to use tools like this for Substrate IDE development? Specifically VSCode *although I personally prefer [Codium](https://vscodium.com/#why)*.

I also will disqualify "use some powerful remote machine with..." in answers, as I aim to efficiently develop **offline** on a moderately resource limited machine.